# Insert array input into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have one form with two HTML input fields where the tag input is an autocomplete form (from the database):

**tags**

- tagId
- tagName

and I want to insert the array into two tables, `document` and `documenttag`:

**Table 1: document**

- `docId`
- `docName`

**Table 2: documenttag**

- `docId`
- `tagId`

But I did not manage to insert the data into the database. Below is my code:

**document-form.php**

```
    <?php

      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tag_name FROM tags");
      $stmt->execute();

      $json = array();  
      while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $json[] = $row['tag_name'];
      }
      $json_array = json_encode($json);

      ?>
      <script>
        $(function(){
          var sampleTags = <?php echo $json_array; ?>

                $('#tags_1').tagit({
                  availableTags: sampleTags,
                });            
              });
            </script>

    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required="required">
    <input id="tags_1" name="tags_1[]" type="text" class="tags form-control">
```

**document-upload-action.php**

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $filesize = round($size / 1024, 2);

            $insert_doc = "INSERT INTO document(docId,docName) VALUES ('$docid','$name')";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($insert_doc);
            $stmt = bindParam(':privacy', $privacy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $privacy = $_POST['privacy'];
            $stmt->execute();

            $tags_1 = implode(",", $tags_1);
            $insert_doc_detail = "INSERT INTO documenttag(docId, tagId) VALUES('$docid','$tags_1')";
            $stmt_1->$conn->prepare($insert_doc_detail);
            $stmt_1->bindParam(':tags_1', $tags_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $tags_1[] = $_POST['tags_1'];
            $stmt_1->execute();
?>
```

Comment: do it throw some exception?

Comment: Where do you get `$docid` and `$name` from? And are you suppose to insert those every time you access this page? And your prepared statements are totally wrong. Please read the manual!

Comment: `"INSERT INTO document(docId,docName) VALUES ('$docid','$name')"` in conjunction with prepared statements does not make sense at all. Use placeholders `:docid` and `:name` and bind **those** parameters to the statement.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: it seems that mistake to invoke the prepare()

Comment: Even if there is no explicit question, the "question" post is well documented and explained, providing source code as well. Not too bad for a SO beginner (I'll vote +1). However, the code itself is as bad, though it is not worth to form a complete answer. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson $docid is a unique id but i did not display in the question. However it inserted into the database. no problem with that

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have updated the question. sorry it is supposed to be 2 different php files. one for the form and one for the form action.

Comment: Start with ``$insert_doc = "INSERT INTO `document` ( `docId` , `docName` ) VALUES ( :docid , :docname )";`` and bind the corresponding parameters. The parameters are `:docid` and `:docname`. Revise the rest of your code like that as well.

Comment: You always include all relevant code (like how you get those variables etc). It's hard to help with code if there are magic variables popping up, since we don't know if they are typos, problems or just omitted. Anyway, the biggest issue you're having is with the prepared statements, like most people already pointed out.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone okay i've done that and the data were inserted. But it inserted the array into 1 row with commas. But if i wanted multiple rows, how should i count the arrays? (each tags seperated with commas will be inserted in a new row)

Comment: `foreach ($array as $item){$statement->execute();} `, provided that you have bound `$item` as parameter to the statement.

Comment: Please update your question to the current so far running version of code, if there is some issue remaining.